# OSError: SavedModel file does not exist. What is .pb format?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to convert my TF model into TFLite.
I found this code online

```
path = # path to the SavedModel directory
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(path) 
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

But it seems to not work.

In this path I have my model.h5 and also model.data-00000-of-00001 + model.index

I created the model in h5 format and also the one that was created when model.save_weights

Any help will be appreciated!
The full error is this:

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: path\model.h5\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

What is a .pb format?

Comment: I read somewhere that means that the model is not saved or placed in a folder named "saved_model.pb". What is the .pb folder format? Should have the code generated it? Thanks

Comment: Hi, .pb format is also known as protobuf, which is a type of file that Tensorflow models are  in the beginning before converting to TFLite format.
Probably you should have that file with .pb format (and also rename it to saved_model.pb, if the name is different) in that path directory.

Comment: Hi @user20035360, please ensure that the path above is the path to the directory in which the model is saved like this "tf_saved_model/" instead of path to the `.pb` file like this "tf_saved_model/saved_model.pb". Kindly refer to this [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate/tflite#after_converting_with_tf2). Thank you!